# How do I animate multiple things at once?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to animate multiple things at once randomly but I CAN'T!!!

I am trying to put it all in one function like this:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var randX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1300);
        var randY = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
        var randSpX = Math.random()*20;
        var randSpY = Math.random()*20;
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
        var i = 0;
        var squareX = new Array();
        var squareY = new Array();
        var color = new Array();
        var anim = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

        function square() {
            for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
                randX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1300);
                randY = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
                randSpX = Math.random()*3;
                randSpY = Math.random()*3;

                squareX[i] = randX;
                squareY[i] = randY;

                context.fillStyle = "#FFF000";
                context.fillRect(squareX[i],squareY[i],20,20);
            }

            randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

            for (i=0;i<10;1++) {
                spX = Math.random()*3;
                spY = Math.random()*3;

                switch (randNum) {
                    case 0:
                        squareX[i] = squareX[i] + spX;
                        squareY[i] = squareY[i] + spY;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        squareX[i] = squareX[i] - spX;
                        squareY[i] = squareY[i] - spY;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        squareX[i] = squareX[i] + spX;
                        squareY[i] = squareY[i] - spY;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        squareX[i] = squareX[i] - spX;
                        squareY[i] = squareY[i] + spY;
                        break;
                }
            }

            anim(square);
        }
```

Unfortunately, this displays my canvas and nothing more.

I've tried to make the square function an object and run the animation code from
another function, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're not starting your animation loop.**

You can start your animation like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(square);
```

BTW, your second for-loop has no effect on your squareX/squareY because the top for-loop is overwriting squareX/squareY.

Here's your code refactored to address these 2 things:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.fillStyle='#fff000';

// create 10 square objects with x,y properties
var squares=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  squares.push({x:Math.random()*300,y:Math.random()*300,});
}

// start animating
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// the animation loop
function animate(){

  // request another animation frame
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
    var s=squares[i];

    // update this square's x & y by -3 to 3 pixels
    s.x+= Math.random()*6-3;
    s.y+= Math.random()*6-3;

    // draw the square
    ctx.fillRect(s.x,s.y,20,20);   

  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I see what you're doing. Thank you.